# Why comp hangs up when reading and writing with sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have read similar posts here but can't understand what is solution.

I have server that creates new thread for each client. Thread is :

```
private static class Capitalizer extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;
        private int clientNumber;

        public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
            log("New connection with client " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
        }

        private void log(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                out.println("Hello, you are a client " + clientNumber);
                out.println("Enter a line with only a period to exit");

                while (true) {
                    String line = in.readLine();
                    if (line == null || line.equals("."))
                        break;
                    out.println(line.toUpperCase());
                    System.out.println("Server capitalized " + line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                log("Connection with client " + clientNumber + " is closed");
            }
        }
    }
```

And client is :

```
public class CapitalizeClient {
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Capitalize Client");
    private JTextField dataField = new JTextField(40);
    private JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 60);

    public CapitalizeClient() {

        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        mainWindow.getContentPane().add(dataField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainWindow.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea));

        dataField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = dataField.getText();
                out.println(text);
                System.out.println("text is sent to server");
                try {
                    String upperCased = in.readLine();
                    if (upperCased == null || upperCased.equals("."))
                        System.exit(0);
                    System.out.println("ActionListener " + text);
                    messageArea.append(upperCased + "\n");
                    dataField.selectAll();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void connectToServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainWindow, "Enter word 'localhost'",
                "Welcome to the capitalization program", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, CapitalizeServer.port);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            messageArea.append(line + "\n");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        CapitalizeClient client = new CapitalizeClient();
        client.mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.mainWindow.pack();
        client.mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        client.connectToServer();
    }
}
```

Capitalizer thread runs ok but ActionListener of dataField runs until it logs message `text is sent to server`.

After that program hangs up on line:

```
String upperCased = in.readLine();
```

in `ActionListener` of `dataField`.

Why is it? 
Thank you!

Comment: Well, if `in.readLine()` returns null once, it's going to *keep* returning null...

Comment: Loop doesn't work it hangs up on first call `in.readLine()`

Comment: Edited to be clearer. Tried again, it really hangs up for very long

Comment: Because you are updating `in` and `out` (on the client) in the main Thread, then reading it in the UI Thread, you should be very careful... mark them both as `volatile` otherwise there's no guarantee the updates will be seen by the UI Thread... but like I said in another comment, try to use a separate Thread for sockets (and only read/write the sockets in that Thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush the `OutputStream` in the server.

```
out.println(line.toUpperCase());
out.flush();
```

Comment: PrintWriter is created with autoFlush flag as true. I tried it and doesn't help

Comment: Ah, I missed that. It should work. Have you tried not using a Buffered reader in the client? That looks unnecessary.

Comment: You are reading the socket in the UI Thread. That's a bad idea. You should have a Thread reading the socket, then when you want to update the UI, run a Runnable with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable)`. But that probably still won't solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the read() method to get the response from server like this:

```
    int i;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((i = in.read(chars,0,1024)) != -1) 
    {
         messageArea.append(String.valueOf(chars) + "\n");
    }
```

Also close the OutputStream once you have sent your stream of data from the server side i.e. in your Capitalize thread, add `out.close()` once you are done.